# amadeus payment distribution process workflow

Tags: amadeus

I am creating an online travel agency, I have a couple of queries regarding Amadeus please guide me on this.

1. Commission decided by the Amadeus or I can change the commission ratio.
2. I want the client payment on my website first then it distributes the payment to Amadeus is it possible?
3. Is Amadeus API handle the payment itself or third party API for payment.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Comission is decided by your agreement with Airline.
2 - You can to charge the creditcard o your gateway or on airlines gateway.
3 - Amadeus API handle the payment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).